# Can't load div with "data-role=page" via ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I try to load a jquery mobile page via ajax into the body tag, the content is not shown at all if `data-role="page"`.

Why does that happen?

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
  $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'http://enrico.bplaced.net/config.php',  
    dataType: 'html',  
  success: function(result) {  
    $('body').html(result);  
  },  
  error: function(obj, status, error) {  
    alert(status + ": " + error);  
  }  
});  
});
```

PHP:
    `print '<div data-role="page" id="startpage">This is not displayed.</div>';`

Comment: Is the a same origin policy violation here? is the page domain `http://enrico.bplaced.net/`?

Comment: what is the url of the page you are working on?

Comment: First are you sure success callback is triggered successfully?

Comment: first of all, `.ready()` is not meant to be used with jQuery Mobile, use `pageinit` event to execute functions when pages are ready in DOM. Secondly, `$('body').html()` will overwrite HTML code in inside `body`. Use `$('body').append(result);` and then `$.mobile.changePage('#startpage');`. Let me know if this works for you.